# $m$ is prime if, and only if, there is $a \in Z_m$ such that $|a|_m = m -1$. where $|\cdot|$ means the order.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Well, $m$ is prime if, and only if, there is $a \in Z_m$ such that $|a|_m = m -1$. where $|\cdot|$ means the order.

What I know:

If $m$ is prime then $m$ has a primitive root. Then there exist an element $a$ such that $|a|_m = m-1.$ In fact, there is $\phi(m-1)$ elements in this way.

For the second part what I tried was:

$|a|_m$ divides $\phi(m)$. But, $|a|_m = m-1.$ Then it is not possible at least if $\phi(m) \neq m -1.$

Comment: @vadim123 thanks, I edited.

Comment: Your argument looks good to me - do you know what to write on the RHS of $
 \phi ( p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}) =\ldots $ ?

Comment: @peterag $\phi(p_1^{n_1}\ldots p_k^{n_k}) = p_1^{n_1 - 1}\ldots p_k^{n_k - 1}\cdot (p_1 - 1)\ldots (p_k - 1)$

Comment: So using  $m = p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ and the corresponding expression for $\phi(m)$, one can/should show $\phi(m) \le (p-1) m/p < m-1$ if $m$ is not prime  - agree?   So your argument looks good.